# How do I create a box plot chart in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I want to create a simple box plot from 1D data, which doesn't seem to be supported by the default *Insert → Charts*. There is a [histogram gadget](https://code.google.com/p/spreadsheethistogram/) but I haven't seen any box plot gadgets.

Do I have to make my own gadget using [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/compound_charts.html#box_charts)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest thing to a Boxplot Chart is a Candlestick Chart.

You could calculate all the data needed to plot a box chart: [The Five Number Summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-number_summary) and plot each serie individually. Apparently, the width of the box isn't important.
I've prepared an example file: [Box Plot example](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdGxCVEhkcVliUUdwTFplQ3NJNWItU0E&usp=sharing) ([sample data](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155130)).

### Screenshots

[image]
[image]

In Google Apps Script, the box charts are un-supported.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Box Plot](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W8gL4EhvPKUYWv25C7AZ3vsJKfv5kX3VBUS9oD22HUU/edit?usp=sharing)**

### References

- [Boxplot Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot)
- [Candlestick Chart](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1409777&topic=30240&ctx=topic)
- [Supported chart types in Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_charts_charttype)

Comment: sorry for the ignorant question, still trying to understand the difference between both, even after reading wikipedia: if not plotting outliers, why not simply using the candlestick?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the addon g(Math) it is under statistical display and will create a box and whisker chart as below. [image]

Comment: box and whisker is typically helpful when charting multiple simultaneously on the same scale. I don't see a way to do that with this...

Comment: I can't find this add-on. Could somebody please provide a link?